# Return an arraylist from an activity in android

Tags: android

I have two activities, activity 1 and activity 2 for example. Activity 1 will call activity 2 and send an arraylist which will then be modified. This I have already done using an intent. What I now want to do, is when activity 2 calls finish() I want that modified arraylist to be sent back to activity 1 so that it has the most upto date version of that arraylist.

Activity 1:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelableArrayList("com.Woody.RingerSchedule", schedules);
Intent i = new Intent(this, addSchedule.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

Activity 2 so far:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
final ArrayList<Schedule> schedules = b.getParcelableArrayList("com.Woody.RingerSchedule");
//modify arraylist
//need code here to return arraylist to activity 1
finish();
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `setResult` with the `Intent` param

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("returnKey","test");
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

You read from the activity that started the activity with `startActivityForResult`

```
//we need a handler for when the secondary activity finishes it's work
//and returns control to this activity...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mEditText1.setText(extras != null ? extras.getString("returnKey"):"nothing returned");
}
```

See this for more example: http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a33/Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities.html

Comment: Yes but for setting the result you want, since it is an array, on the activity started should use "putParcelableArrayListExtra" function instead of "putExtra". 
And for the activity which get the result should use "getParcelableArrayExtra" instead.